# How do I complete the first mission of ArmA as a special forces operative?

Tags: arma-armed-assault

I've been trying to beat the first mission as a special forces operative destroying a convoy.  No matter what I do I can't get through the mission.  I've used my IED to pop the APC, I've shot trucks full of guys and I still get taken down every time.

Any tips for completing this mission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You're a good shooter: On the way to the convoy is a house. You can hide Your own convoy behind it and climb the ladder of the scaffold to the first floor. From here You can snipe the enemies down. However, this is very hard - most importantly, You have to be very quick as the enemies will locate You after a few shots.

You don't necessarily have to eliminate the whole convoy from this position - taking out at least some enemies might grant You a benefit for Your second wave of attack.